# Couchbase - JOIN an array within a document with another document in the same bucket

Tags: couchbase, sql++

I am struggling to perform join queries between two types of document in the same bucket in Couchbase.

Details:
Bucket Name: `lifext-stage`

IMPORTANT NOTE: Both documents are in the same bucket but both documents have different type field which can be used to identify them when querying.

First Doument has the `type` field set to `moment`

Second Document has the `type` field set to `user`

First Document Schema:

```
{
      "allCongrats": [
        {
          "congratulatory": "“The invariable mark of wisdom is to see the miraculous in the common.” -Ralph Waldo Emerson",
          "orderedId": 14
        }
      ],
      "congratulatory": null,
      "cueRecommendations": [
        {
          "iconName": "Waking_Up",
          "recommendation": "Waking Up"
        },
      ],
      "deliveryMethod": "audio",
      "description": "Complete a 60-second practice for unwinding stress by taking in the good",
      "duration": 60000,
      "effort": "med",
      "id": "moment-82435b7dca1eff75066b14a7c47ac046",
      "moduleId": "module-48f41a55ab24166c7ab1d1d8d825c776",
      "moduleType": "CULTIVATE_OPTIMISM",
      "orderedId": 1,
      "practice": "Gratitude",
      "textDuration": "60 sec",
      "title": "60 Seconds of Optimism",
      "type": "moment"
    }
```

Second Document Schema:

```
{
      "assessments": [],
      "cohortId": "cohort-a855864e-12b9-4e34-bd1f-2a89e581de1b",
      "dashboardIntroSeen": false,
      "email": "pros@aviahealthinnovation.com",
      "firstAssessmentCompleted": false,
      "firstName": "Phil",
      "focusId": null,
      "id": "user-00259a727b52cf35595e175134f49584",
      "lastName": "Ros",
      "longestStreak": 0,
      "modules": [],
      "moments": [
        {
          "completedDates": null,
          "lastCompletedMomentDate": null,
          "lastCongratulatoryId": null,
          "moduleId": "module-48f41a55ab24166c7ab1d1d8d825c776",
          "momentId": "moment-82435b7dca1eff75066b14a7c47ac046",
          "orderedId": 0,
          "userMomentId": "userMoment-58445416-9878-45d9-8221-6d6f76bf0a42"
        }
      ],
      "organizationId": "organization-fd779338-1361-4789-8da8-1ea37b0a3906",
      "signupTs": "2017-11-29T19:49:25.613Z",
      "streak": 0,
      "tokenValidator": "d9dcf699c23bacd33d6d841c454447d375990c51daa109cd5ffa5ff29bc7e6b0b76a26825267efb6b6873533ae711f82",
      "type": "user"
    }
```

As you can see the second document has a moments arrays which contains the `momentId` key. This `momentId` key maps to the `id` key in the first document.

I want to join each moments item in the second document with the first document and return the result.

Expected result for this example:

```
{
      "allCongrats": [
        {
          "congratulatory": "“The invariable mark of wisdom is to see the miraculous in the common.” -Ralph Waldo Emerson",
          "orderedId": 14
        }
      ],
      "congratulatory": null,
      "cueRecommendations": [
        {
          "iconName": "Waking_Up",
          "recommendation": "Waking Up"
        },
      ],
      "deliveryMethod": "audio",
      "description": "Complete a 60-second practice for unwinding stress by taking in the good",
      "duration": 60000,
      "effort": "med",
      "id": "moment-82435b7dca1eff75066b14a7c47ac046",
      "moduleId": "module-48f41a55ab24166c7ab1d1d8d825c776",
      "moduleType": "CULTIVATE_OPTIMISM",
      "orderedId": 1,
      "practice": "Gratitude",
      "textDuration": "60 sec",
      "title": "60 Seconds of Optimism",
      "type": "moment",
      "completedDates": null,
      "lastCompletedMomentDate": null,
      "lastCongratulatoryId": null,
      "momentId": "moment-82435b7dca1eff75066b14a7c47ac046",
      "orderedId": 0,
      "userMomentId": "userMoment-58445416-9878-45d9-8221-6d6f76bf0a42"
    }
```

Here are some of the queries that I have tried but failed to get any results:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT um
FROM `lifext-stage` a 
UNNEST a.moments as um
WHERE a.type="user") as u
INNER JOIN `lifext-stage` m
ON u.um.momentId = m.id
WHERE m.type="moment"
```

The above query gives me following error:

```
[
  {
    "code": 3000,
    "msg": "syntax error - at u",
    "query_from_user": "SELECT *\nFROM (SELECT um\nFROM `lifext-stage` a \nUNNEST a.moments as um\nWHERE a.type=\"user\") as u\nINNER JOIN `lifext-stage` m\nON u.um.momentId = m.id\nWHERE m.type=\"moment\""
  }
]
```

Second query that I tried:

```
SELECT g.*, ARRAY_AGG({"node":n, "data":d}) AS node_data
FROM `lifext-stage` AS g UNNEST g.moments AS n JOIN `lifext-stage` AS d ON n.momentId = d.id
WHERE g.type="user" AND d.type="moment"
```

I have been struggling with this for the past two days, any help in this regard will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2):

Requires Couchbase Version 5.50

```
CREATE INDEX ix1 ON `lifext-stage` (id) WHERE type = "moment";

SELECT *
FROM `lifext-stage` AS u
UNNEST u.moments AS um
JOIN `lifext-stage` AS m ON um.momentId = m.id
WHERE m.type = "moment" AND u.type = "user";
```

The following blog has use case examples on ANSI JOIN.

https://blog.couchbase.com/ansi-join-support-n1ql/

Comment: Is there any solution for version 4.4? Because my client is running version 4.4 on production and I cant really take the risk to upgrade it atleast for now

Comment: The document key also same same id. Try this SELECT *
FROM `lifext-stage` AS u
JOIN `lifext-stage` AS m ON KEYS u.moments[*].momentId 
WHERE m.type = "moment" AND u.type = "user";